# Problema em um Script PlayerMoviment de Char no Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity3d, jogos

Problema em um Script PlayerMoviment de Char no Unity 5
Suposto problema na linha 70 nos "Quaternion" [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMoviment : MonoBehaviour 
{
 //velocidade do Mago
 public float speed = 6f;

 //Vetor responsavel pelo movimento do Mago
 Vector3 movement;

 //Responsavel pela transiçao da animaçao
 Animator anim;

 //Responsavel pela fisica do objeto
 Rigidbody playerRigidbody;

 //Mascara de chao
 int floorMask;

 //Informaçoes para magia
 float camRayLenght = 100f;

 void Awake()
 { //Atribuir mascara de camada
  floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor"); 

  //Atribuir as referencias
  anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
  playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();

 }



 void FixedUpdate()
 {
  float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
  float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");

  Move (h, v);
  Turning ();
  Animating (h, v);
 }



 //movimento do Mago
 void Move (float h, float v)
 { //Determina o movimento
  movement.Set (h, 0f, v);
  //normaliza o movimento
  movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
  //Efetua o movimento do Mago
  playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);

 }
 //Movimento Giratorio do Mago
 void Turning ()
 {
  Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

  RaycastHit floorHit;

  if (Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLenght, floorMask)) 
  {
   Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
   playerToMouse.y = 0f;

   Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
   playerRigidbody.MovePosition(newRotation);
  
  }  


 }

 void Animating(float h, float v)
 {
  bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f;

  anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", walking); 
 }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o código não uma imagem dele assim fica mais fácil pra outros membros testarem

Comment: qual erro? Procure postar o erro para facilitar a analise @CmdsaPessoa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A causa do erro é simples e direta: o método [`MovePosition`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) espera como parâmetro um `Vector3` e não um `Quaternion`. Como você está passando um `Quaternion` como parâmetro na linha...

```
playerRigidbody.MovePosition(newRotation);
```

...a ferramenta gera o erro para indicar o parâmetro inválido.

A questão então é: o que você queria fazer? Se você queria orientar a transformação (fazer o objeto "ficar voltado"/"olhar" para a direção do mouse), é só fazer como [no exemplo da documentação](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html), e trocar essa linha por:

```
transform.rotation = newRotation;
```